# How to align sprites sequentially in a line and extract them as a png format with TexturePacker?

Tags: flutter, texturepacker, flame

I want to align 15 picture from [this pack](https://www.gameart2d.com/the-boy---free-sprites.html) in one line using `TexturePacker` and create a png file as sprite sheet to create an animation using [`FireAtlas`](https://fire-atlas.flame-engine.org/#/) afterward. I tried a lot but couldn't create such output. I am using Flame library in Flutter and there is no output for Flame in [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/) software, so I have to use many tools to get the desired output.

Comment: Updated my answer now when flame_texturepacker 2.0.0 is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flame_texturepacker` is now updated to flame 1.0.0 and nullsafety, so you can just depend on `flame_texturepacker: ^2.0.0`.

**Old answer:**

Something like this should work:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';

extension TexturePackerExtension on Game {
  Future<List<Sprite>> loadTexturePack(
    String imagePath,
    String dataPath,
  ) async {
    final json = await Flame.assets.readJson(dataPath)
        as Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>;
    final image = await Flame.images.load(imagePath);

    final sprites = json['frames']?.values.map((dynamic value) {
      final frameData = value['frame'] as Map<String, int>;
      final x = frameData['x']!;
      final y = frameData['y']!;
      final width = frameData['w']!;
      final height = frameData['h']!;

      return Sprite(
        image,
        srcPosition: Vector2(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble()),
        srcSize: Vector2(width.toDouble(), height.toDouble()),
      );
    });

    return sprites?.toList() ?? [];
  }
}
```

Converted from `flame_texturepacker` to Flame version 1.0.0.

Just import it in your game class file and call it:

```dart
import texture_packer_extension.dart;

class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  ...

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    final sprites = await loadTexturePack('myImage.png', 'myJson.json');
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: old answer gives `MappedIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Sprite>` error.

Comment: updating `flame_texturepacker: ^2.0.0+2` solved the issue. How to decrease the size of the character?

Comment: @DB either set the scale or the size of the SpriteAnimationComponent.